# generic function to handle http request

Tags: go, generics, gorilla

Below is the generic function to handle http request

```
    func Process[Req GoLibRequest, Resp GoLibResponse](w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request, processFunc func(request GoLibRequest, response *GoLibResponse) error) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {

        request := GoLibRequest{MsgId: GetMsgID()}
        response := GoLibResponse{MsgId: GetMsgID()}

        if err := json.NewDecoder(r.Body).Decode(&request); err != nil {
            Logger.Errorf("Decoding body failed: %v", err)
            resErr := NewHTTPError(err, 400, "Bad request : invalid JSON.", "EGN002")
            response.Error = resErr
            json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response)
            return
        }

        resErr := processFunc(request, &response)
        if resErr != nil {
            Logger.Errorf("Unable to process request: %v", resErr)
            response.Error = resErr
            w.WriteHeader(http.StatusInternalServerError)
        } else {
            w.WriteHeader(200)
        }

        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
        if err := json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(response); err != nil {
            log.Printf("Encoding response failed: %v", err)
        }
    }

}
```

how do i pass this function to mux router properly .

currently passing as below, but getting errors

```
sm := http.NewServeMux()
    sm.HandleFunc("/login", lib.Process(ProcessLogin))
    sm.Handle("/metrics", promhttp.Handler())
```

Answer (score 0):

Your process function takes three arguments but you are only passing one `lib.Process(ProcessLogin)`.

Try refactoring your process function without `http.ResponseWriter` and `http.Request`:

```
    func Process[Req GoLibRequest, Resp GoLibResponse](processFunc func(request GoLibRequest, response *GoLibResponse) error) http.HandlerFunc {
```